# For any finite set of vectors $ S \subset V$, Gram determinant $\Gamma \geq 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

There are two cases to the proof:

(we are in unitary spaces)

I) when we have n=k, we easily prove it as it follows:

$\Gamma(S) = \det (S) = \det ( M^*M)=|M^*||M|=|M|^2\geq 0$

II) when $ n < k$ :

it can be done it two ways. The first is geometrically; according to the Roché's theorem, vectors are linearly dependent if $|S| = 0$, or if they are linearly independent when $|S| \neq 0$. From here we know that a determinant represents a volume of a parallelotope. Therefore volume cannot be negative, hence we proved it.

My question is, how do we prove, the second case, if we do not look geometrically. If we say $\Gamma = \det(M^*M)\geq 0$ and we take an arbitrary vector $a\in U$, $a=(\alpha_{1},...,\alpha_{n})_{E}$, where $E$ is the basis.

How do we from this:

$a^*M^*Ma\geq 0$

prove that this

$\Gamma= |S| = \det(M^*M) \geq 0$ must be true?